# RDD.toLocalIterator eager evaluation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to perform an action on a driver for each element of RDD without calling `.collect()`. The first idea is to use `RDD.toLocalIterator()`:

```
val config = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[10]").setAppName("xxx")
val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(config)
val ints: RDD[Int] = sc.parallelize(1 to 50)
val doubled = ints.map(i => {
  Thread.sleep(200)
  println(s"map $i" + Thread.currentThread())
  i * 2
})

doubled.toLocalIterator.foreach(i => {
  println(s"got $i" + Thread.currentThread())
})
```

But in this case computation of the next partition starts only after consuming the previous partition. So overall computation takes too much time.
I invented the following hack:

```
doubled.cache()
//force rdd to be materialized
println(doubled.count())
//traverse cached rdd
doubled.toLocalIterator.foreach(i => { 
  println(s"got $i" + Thread.currentThread())
})
```

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score -2):

why you don't just use the `RDD.foreach` method I think this can perform the same as your example giving in the question. using this you can make profit of the parallel processing offering by spark `RDD`s

Comment: `foreach` runs on workers, I need to run a function on a driver

Comment: if you run the function on driver, I think that you cant benefit from the parallel processing offered by spark